# How do you handle request mappings and path variables using non-MVC HttpRequestHandlerServlet?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I'm trying to use Spring Web on Tomcat to build an API server.  This is just a request-response API, not a full web app - it won't have any web pages or static assets like images.  As such, I think SpringWebMVC is the wrong technology since I don't actually want the MVC part of it, so I'm just just trying to use plain old SpringWeb.

Unfortunately, practically every tutorial I've found online uses the `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet` which is from the MVC package, not from the base package.  In the base package, the only viable HttpServlet implementation I found was `org.springframework.web.context.support.HttpRequestHandlerServlet`.  However, this servlet doesn't seem to honor `@RequestMapping` or `@RequestBody` or `@ResponseBody` annotations in the handler.

I thought perhaps I'd just create multiple handler servlets and just use the `url-pattern` on each of them in the `web.xml` to route them correctly, but it turns out `url-pattern` doesn't support path variables either (at least as far as I can tell).

So is there a way to properly set up this servlet to be able to handle request mappings with path variables like so?:

```
GET /foo/{fooId}
POST /foo/{fooId}/fooOperation
POST /bar/{barId}/barOperationA
POST /bar/{barId}/barOperationB
POST /bar/{barId}/barOperationC
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "don't want the MVC part of it"? Can you explain in your own words what you think it provides that you don't want? It looks like you're going to a _lot_ of extra trouble.

Comment: Well there's no model or view in this application, it's just a controller.  I suppose I could still use SpringMVC if that's what people recommend, but it seems like it's not the right tool for the job given that SpringMVC is generally meant to be used for web apps.  What's the point of the SpringWeb and SpringWebMVC being in separate packages if you have to use both of them even to build a simple request-reply service?

Comment: What do you mean "no model or view"? How are you getting data into it? (Note that JSON or XML _is_ a view.) `spring-web` provides modules such as RestTemplate that are usable _as client-only_ tools, whereas `spring-webmvc` provides the server functions. I strongly recommend reading the official guides for [building REST services](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) and [using Boot to handle all the plumbing you're asking about](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/).

Comment: Use `RestController` annotation from spring web. [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html)